# JPQL LEFT OUTER JOIN with conditions on right table

Tags: java, postgresql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, jpql

I'm looking for the JPQL named query for this postgres statement:

```
SELECT e.* ROM employees e LEFT JOIN report_employees re ON re.fk_employee_id = e.id AND re.fk_report_id = ? WHERE re.fk_employee_id IS NULL
```

This is what I got, but it returns nothing while the SQL query statement returns 117 rows:

```
SELECT e FROM Employee e LEFT JOIN e.reportEmployeeList AS re WHERE (re.employeeId IS NULL AND re.reportId = :reportId)
```

This is the list in EntityA:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "entityAId")
private List<ReportEmployee> entityBList;
```

I am using Eclipselink 2.5.2, JPA 2.1 and Glassfish 4.1

Edit:
I've adjusted some of the names. Makes for easier reading.

Comment: I'm not sure the point of the query, as the b.fk_entity_a_id cannot both be null and reference a valid a.id.  What are the results of the SQL query and what are you really trying to filter?  My guess is your 117 results are all nulls values.

Comment: I have 3 tables, Employees, Report and ReportEmployees. With a specific event, a new report is generated and a some employees of the Employees table are copied to the ReportEmployees. Now what I need is all the Employees that are not in the ReportEmployees table for that specific Report. 
The SQL query returns the correct 117 results. Tested with a specific Report where there are 15/132 Employees registered for that Report. So the remaining Employees should be 117. (I checked the values, the ones in the ReportEmployee were not in my resultset

Comment: Your changes don't make sense with respect to the mapping provided.  How does an employee have a list of ReportEmployees?  Isn't report_employee that references Report?  Your SQL query is not giving you what you say you want - it is giving you all Employees that are not associated to ANY report employee, not just the report in question.  If you add another report, you will see those employees are filtered as well, regardless of the report ID used.